# Parse 1st API response and create a second call to API

Tags: json, api, salesforce, duedil-api

I'm new to API's but made a bit of headway today in integrating a call to the Duedil (UK Company information directory).

I'm doing this in Salesforce using Buttons

My first call is an easy search on Account Name in Salesforce

CALL 1:
http://api.duedil.com/open/search?q={!Account.Name}&api_key=MY_API_KEY

"Arjo Fine Paper" is the Account.

The response returned is:

```
{
"response":
{"pagination":"http:\/\/api.duedil.com\/open\/search?query=Arjo+Fine+Paper&total_results=3&limit=5&last_result=1",
"data":[
{
"company_number":"**00961440**",
"locale":"United Kingdom",
"name":"Arjo Wiggins Fine Papers Limited",
"uri":"http:\/\/api.duedil.com\/open\/uk\/company\/00961440.json"
},
{
"company_number":"01870033",
"locale":"United Kingdom",
"name":"Arjo Wiggins Fine Papers Export Limited",
"uri":"http:\/\/api.duedil.com\/open\/uk\/company\/01870033.json"
},
{
"company_number":"00683415",
"locale":"United Kingdom",
"name":"Arjo Wiggins Fine Papers Holdings Limited",
"uri":"http:\/\/api.duedil.com\/open\/uk\/company\/00683415.json"
}
]
}
}
```

What I want to do is parse the first Company number and then display the results 
e.g. "https://www.duedil.com/company/00961440"

Do I embed Call 1 in some JS that can parse out the answer from Call 1?

Thanks for any help/steers.

Comment: FYI: we're building new API https://www.duedil.com/api/docs so soon you'd be able to use this new version that will allow you to generate a PHP client using Swagger specification. That should save you a lot of time on the integration side.

Answer (score 0):

Try to have a look at the Salesforce doc ( [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_json_jsonparser.htm) ) for parsing the JSon Strings or Serializing the information back to some Collection of Objects (or Wrapper classes).

You may also have a look at serializing your information (in form of Collection, Object or a String) using `JSON.serialize()` method while to get the information back (Collection, Object or String) you need to use `JSON.desrialize()` by typecasting it.